# No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I didn't specify any transport in `hubConnection.start()`, but I still got the transport failure.
I am using IE 10 and IIS 8.0. Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

The code to connect to SignalR server:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var hubConnection = $.hubConnection("http://myserver.com:8031");
        var notificationHub = hubConnection.createHubProxy("Notification");
        hubConnection.logging = true;

        notificationHub.on("calculationResultReceived", function (result) {
            addLog("Time elapsed: " + result.timeElapsed + ", finalResult: " + result.finalResult+ ", ID: " + result.jobId);
            }
        });

        hubConnection.start().done(function () {
            notificationHub.invoke("Echo")
                .done(function (msg) { addLog("Notification hub connection established successfully" + "\n" + msg); })
                .fail(function (message) { addLog("Failed to register push channel"); });
        }).fail(function (message) {
            addLog("The connection cannot be established: " + message)
        });
    });
```

The console log of the IE10:

> [23:10:06 UTC+0800] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notification'.
>   [23:10:06 UTC+0800] SignalR: Negotiating with
>   'http://myserver.com:8031/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notification%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'.
>   [23:10:07 UTC+0800] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
>   [23:10:07 UTC+0800] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
>   [23:10:12 UTC+0800] SignalR: foreverFrame timed out when trying to
>   connect.   [23:10:12 UTC+0800] SignalR: Stopping forever frame.
>   [23:10:12 UTC+0800] SignalR: Opening long polling request to
>   'http://myserver.com:8031/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=c39XZZSbiQZDnXbf6vOm8zt8wTQrStyPg8qchxWFevyp9BN2yxslU6YAahRdrsy7W0LOc%2BW5FMfRhQe10o%2B2ihlprs9803heDkD2S1Qo4j8oI1kmUA5fPXoBlcP3Ygrk&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notification%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
>   [23:10:17 UTC+0800] SignalR: longPolling timed out when trying to
>   connect.   [23:10:17 UTC+0800] SignalR: Aborted xhr request.
>   [23:10:17 UTC+0800] SignalR: Stopping connection.   [23:10:17
>   UTC+0800] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.

### ADD 1

I checked my IIS8 installation, and enabled the **WebSocket** feature. But still the same error, though the error message changed a bit.
[image]

Comment: Have you hooked the PreSendRequestHeaders event by chance? This might be related to the following issue affecting SignalR 2.1.0: http://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3116 You can work around the issue by removing the PreSendRequestHeaders event or by downgrading to SignalR 2.0.3

Comment: Could you try by updating your JSON.NET version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to diable browserlink feature in Visual Studio. To disable browserlink click Browser Link dropdown and uncheck *Enable Browser Link* ([Using Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)).

(Source: [github.com/SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3148), author: netsrotr)